# Tag variable to HTML class (or div) name in Django template

Tags: html, django

So I have this `view.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Table

def table_view(request):
    table_count = Table.objects.count()
    return render(request,
                  'table/table_view.html',
                  {'table_count': table_count,
                   'table_list': range(table_count)})
```

and my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Dashboard{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Table Management</h1>

  <div id="table_display">
    {% for table in table_list %}
      <button class="button table1">Table {{table|add:"1"}}</button>
    {% endfor %}

  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to tag the class name for the buttons with the value of variable `table`. For eg.: `table1`, `table2`, `table3`,etc. as the `for` loop iterate through the `table_list`. Could anyone advise how I go about doing this? Note that `table_list` starts from `0` and I would like for the name to start from `1`.

Comment: Does this not work? What is the output it gives?

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane In my code above, all buttons have the same name ```table1```. This is the part I want to tag ```button class="button table1"``` (not the text display within the button).

Comment: You need to do this to class also. Or you can edit your post with, *what you get* vs *what you want* output.

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane Thanks. I didn't know it works the same way. This is what I change ```<button class="button table{{table|add:"1"}}">Table {{table|add:"1"}}</button>```. I test this in my ```.css``` file and it works. Closing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `{{ forloop.counter }}` if you want numeration starts from `1` or `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` if you want it to start form `0`

```
 {% for table in table_list %}
      <button class="button table1">Table {{ forloop.counter }}</button>
 {% endfor %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for